# Symfony - API platform - Is it possible for api platform pagination to start from 0

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Page number for Symfony API platform always starts with page=1

Is it possible to make it dynamic, I want it to start with page=0 which will be the first page.

I dont see any such configuration in https://api-platform.com/docs/core/configuration/

Comment: Why would u need such behavior ?

Comment: Just don't do this. I know it isn't the cases for PHP arrays (item 1 = index 0), but for pages, the 1st page should be ...1. 

Comment: Datatables first page start from 0